# Can't select <article> selector with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, css-selectors, nokogiri

Here is the HTML source I am trying to scrape:

```
<section class="articles">
  <article role="article">
    <a href="..."></a>
  </article>
  <article role="article">
    <a href="..."></a>
  </article>
```

I am trying to scrape the href with this:

```
require 'open-air'
require 'nokogiri'

url = "http://www.vg.no/sport/langrenn/"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url)) 

doc.css(".articles article").each do |i|
  location = i.at_css("a")[:href]
puts location
end
```

I have tried so many other things, but this seems like it should work. I have been able to scrape content using other selectors on this page, just nothing inside of the `<article></article>` tags, which contains everything I need.

Comment: The above works for me if I load that HTML up as a `Nokogiri::HTML.fragment`.  Are you sure that's what the HTML really looks like?

Comment: That HTML doesn’t actually appear on the page at the url in your code. It is loaded dynamically by javascript.

Comment: @matt So there is no way to scrape the content from the <article> tags? I don't know of any scraper tools that work for javascript...

Comment: Not with plain Nokogiri. You might be able to use something like Capybara. It’s not something I’ve done though.